# Why wrapping call to function returning by value in hana::always circumvent requirements of ranges::views::join? Or maybe it doesn't?

Tags: c++, c++20, boost-hana, std-ranges

This function, fed with any `int`, returns a `std::vector<int>` by value:

```cpp
auto make = [](int){
    return std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
};
```

Therefore, such a thing can't work

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
auto z = v | std::ranges::views::transform(make)
           | std::ranges::views::join; // fails to compile
```

because, I understand (but correct me if I'm wrong), when the iterator wrapped in `join` advances, it triggers the generations of the vectors by means of `make`, but those temporary are already destroyed by the time the iterator in `join` is dereferenced.

However, the following doesn't fail:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
auto z = v | std::ranges::views::transform(boost::hana::always(make(int{})))
           | std::ranges::views::join;
```

Why is that? What mechanism is being introduced by the use of `always`?

I think the following is proof that both functions, `make` and `always(make(int{}))`, return a temporary. Am I making a mistake?

```cpp
static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<decltype(make(int{}))>);
static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<decltype(boost::hana::always(make(int{}))(int{}))>);
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WbEY4jEnG).

Comment: This appears to work fine with gcc trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/8ja9qMhzj Edit: gcc 11.2 also seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate issues.

- `join_view`'s restriction on joining ranges of prvalue ranges is a defect in C++20 that has been corrected by [P2328R1](https://wg21.link/P2328R1). `transform(make) | join` should Just Work on a standard library implementing the defect resolution (such as libstdc++ trunk).
- `hana::always` returns different things depending on whether it is invoked as an lvalue or rvalue. It returns an lvalue reference when invoked as an lvalue and a prvalue when invoked as an rvalue. `transform` always invokes as lvalue, while your `static_assert` is checking the result of invoking as rvalue.